# Why don't writers make more use of the word "abracadabra"?

Tags: etymology

If you want to import a sense of the miraculous into your text, why not use *abracadabra* which has been available in English since the late 17th century, and originated in Gnostic writings in the 2nd century? My instinct tells me these would have been Greek, but the OED claims they were Latin. Is this correct?

Comment: What is the question here? Why writers don't do it (answers are pure opinion); or what the origin of the word is (general reference)?

Comment: Because magicians ruined it.

Comment: OED says *The etymology of post-classical Latin **abracadabra** has been the subject of much conjecture; no documentation has been found to support any of the various conjectures which have been put forward. **Some have suggested an origin within Latin or Greek***. So I think it's pointless asking ELU to debate whether OP's "instincts" are correct regarding the etymology. And I think asking why writers don't make more use of the word is even more pointless, since all answers will probably just be opinions.

Comment: @Amory - Yes, quite true. And, if magicians left any life in the word, that was snuffed out by [Steve Miller](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SzLguP2hfjw).

Comment: Avada Kedavra! [Abra, Kadabra (and Alakazam)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abra,_Kadabra,_and_Alakazam).

Comment: I think it is unfair to blame The Steve Miller Band.  As you can see in the [ngram,](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=abracadabra&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) the decline in use happened prior to the 1982 release of the single "Abracadabra" by Steve Miller Band.

Comment: Because not all stories are about wizards?

Comment: You should change the subject of your question to reflect the etymology discussion.

Comment: Yes, Apologies. I was simply attempting to get some discussion on the subject. I have learned more by going to the printed Shorter OED. (the Kindle version is abbreviated). But I have learned nothing that has not been revealed here.  My grandson (aged 8) has a range of magic words he uses when performing conjuring tricks. My wife who is of Chinese descent has taught him a few Chinese ones, but Abracadabra remains a favourite of his and the English pantomime season. I never knew that it had such classical origins.

Comment: @Lumberjack - I didn't mean to imply causality. I just meant to say that, if I was a writer hesitant to use the word _before_ the song, the song would have made me even _more_ hesitant after it hit the charts. BTW, your ngram is a nice piece of research.

Comment: @J.R., prior to Steve Miller, there was [Black Sabbath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbra_Cadabra), too. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The first known mention of the word was in the third century AD in a book called Liber Medicinalis (sometimes known as De Medicina Praecepta Saluberrima) by Quintus Serenus Sammonicus. [[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abracadabra)]  In the book, the author makes mention of Abraxas Stones which were believed to have magical properties.

According to the online etymology dictionary, the root for Abracadabra is [Abraxas,](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php) (Greek) which makes sense when considering the first known usage of the word.

The Abraxas Stone as described in Liber Medicinalis was an amulet in the shape of a triangle, engraved with the word Abracadabra as follows:

[image]

These references seem to support your assertion that the root of the word is Greek, despite the fact that its first known usage was in a Latin book from the third century AD.

EDIT: Someone less ignorant than myself may be able to assist.  Here is the first mention of abracadabra in the [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=y5FOAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=abracadabra&f=false) mentioned above.

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=y5FOAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=abracadabra&f=false]

Does this not say specifically that the word is Greek?  Graecis is Latin for Greek, but I can't read the entirety of the text.

Comment: If it was Greek, why is the diagram in the Latin alphabet?

Comment: Someone less ignorant than me may be able to use [this page](http://books.google.com/books?id=y5FOAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=abracadabra&f=false) of the book to determine whether or not that is the case.

Comment: The Latin says: What the Greeks call *hemitritaeos* is more deadly. Our ancestors could not name it in our language, nor did they want to. On a piece of paper, write the following, i.e. the abracadabra.

Comment: Sorry, better than *nor did they want to* is *nor did they (feel the) need to*.

Comment: According to Perseus, _ἡμιτριταῖος_ means, “_half every three days_. **τρόπος ἡμιτριταῖος**, of a _semi-tertian fever_.” (A semi-tertian fever is apparently one “having a paroxysm every day, and a second stronger one every two days” [Wiktionary])

Answer (score -2):

Language is magic, and writing even more so, so magic words often relate to it.

*Abracadabra* is a mnemonic for the Latin alphabet, or at least the first part of it, i.e,

- **A-B-C-D**

Other magic words in the same sequence (you can see the algorithm they follow)
that didn't make it into common parlance include

- *Efragahefra* for **E-F-G-H**
- *Ijrakalijra* for **I-J-K-L**

Note that the vowel letters are distributed throughout the alphabet just about right to make this mnemonic useful. Of course, the mnemonic came after the development of the Latin alphabet, rather than being a cause of the order. But magic need not distinguish between cause and effect.

Comment: *Abracadabra is a mnemonic for the Latin alphabet* What is your source for this? Also, where else have you seen *Efragahefra* or *Ijrakalijra*?